# I have Master (Equivalent) and Bachelor degree (Conditionally comparable), which one will be used to assess for German work Visa

Tags: germany, working-visas, blue-card, indian-citizens

I have been offered the role of “Software developer” but my three years master degree is in 'is Equivalent' and my Bachelor degree is 'Conditionally comparable' status in the Anabin database. Both universities are H+ status.

I am applying for a regular work/employment visa and not a Blue Card. I currently reside in India. The salary being offered is also above 44,000 EUR.

I would like to know which degree will be evaluated. My employer is asking to do a fast track visa processing.